# Using matlab (or some other tool) to perform convolution?

Tags: matlab, homework

I have an homework assignment in my signals and systems class involving various tasks having to do with signal analysis, but my main question is this:
I am given a system described by the differential equation:

$$a_1 y'(t)+a_0 y(t) = b_1 x'(t) + b_0 x(t)$$

I am given 15 values of the **response function** and am able to graph it in Matlab using the plot function with 2 vectors.

I have been able to find the **impulse response** $h(t)$ of the system. To my understanding, one can find the output $y(t)$ of any LTI system to an input signal $x(t)$ by **convolving** that input signal $x(t)$ with the impulse response $h(t)$ of the system.

However, my input signal $x(t)$ and impulse response $h(t)$ are in 2 different formats, as I have the **analytic** (as a decaying exponential function) form for my impulse response $h(t)$.

How do you all suggest I go about convolving the two?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you provide more details? For example, what do you mean by "response function" and "functional form"?

Comment: the term **response function** just below the differential equation do not make much sense, please clarify which **signal** that reponse function refers to: a-) input $x(t)$, b-) output $y(t)$, c-) impulse response $h(t)$...

Comment: I'm sorry, by response function, I meant excitation. I have values of the excitation in the way of points. Sorry about the imprecision.

Comment: so can you please edit your question according to **excitation** being $x(t)$